# Rails form_for not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create a small rails blog, and have run into an error. I think I've messed up the naming convention of something here... but I can't find anything specific enough to help me and give me the answer.

I have a route of

```
resources :blog
```

and a controller which has the following

```
class BlogController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @blogs = Blog.all
  end

  def show
    @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @blog = Blog.new
  end

end
```

When I try to set up a form on the new.html.erb page, it links to routing which states

```
undefined method `blogs_path'
```

My route is blog, not blogs... where am I going wrong? I would like the route to be /blog.

Comment: I'd recommend saying `resources :blogs` as resources are usually in plural form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the conventions, rename your controller file to `blogs_controller.rb` and the class inside of it to `BlogsController`. Then, in your `routes.rb`: `resources :blogs`. It should all work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I went back and set up the blog using the standard naming convention.

Answer (score 1):

As already said, it should be :

```
resources :blogs
```

And I think the controller should use the plural too : BlogsController

Answer (score 1):

To find what's wrong with urls you can use `rake routes` command

Values in first column *Prefix* are names of helpers you can use as `prefix_url` or `prefix_path`